# How can I read data saved with NSUserDefaults in the Apportable version of my app, from a pure Android version?

Tags: apportable

I'll be updating an old app I'd ported with Apportable to a pure Android version. I want to be able to rescue users' old data.

The old data was a dictionary saved with `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: forKey:]`
I assumed I might find it in the SharedPreferences of Android, but going through the keys in `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)` didn't find anything.

I would very much appreciate any pointers.

Comment: I believe it uses the file system. Continue investigating from https://github.com/apportable/Foundation/blob/master/System/Foundation/src/NSUserDefaults.m